# Looking for a word pattern in string

Tags: c#, .net, string, linq

I need to find the maximum number of letters which are between two similar strings. For example consider the following string:

```
progxrammerrxproxgrammer
```

I need to find the `rx` length which is 2 between the first `progxrammer` and second `proxgrammer`. To achieve this I need to find a way to identify a subset of the above string can be rearranged to form the word "programmer". As an another example consider this:

```
xprogxrmaxemrppprmmograeiruu
```

Again it should find `pp` which is between two set of `programmer` words.

I have tried the following, but I have really no idea how can I achieve this?

```
public static int programmerStrings(string s)
{
    var firstPart = s.ToLower().Contains("programmer");

    var secondPart = s.ToLower().Contains("programmer");

    return (secondPart - firstPart).Length;
}
```

Comment: Erm, is this homework?

Comment: So you need to search from the front until you find each letter in "programmer" and then search from the end for the same thing and take whatever the length is between the two positions you end up at?

Comment: @juharr Yes. But for second pattern it could be started from any where, not necessary end.

Comment: `Contains()` returns you IF your string was found but you're looking for the position. This can be done using `IndexOf()` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.indexof?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: I'm saying you need to search from the end to find where it "starts"

Comment: @ChristophLütjen That will not help here as they are not looking for an exact match, but just a collection of letters that include the letters in a word.

Comment: @juharr Exactly.

Comment: Also what should the result be?  The actual string between or just the length?

Comment: @juharr Just the length.

Answer (score 2):

Basically you need to search the characters starting from the beginning and then again from the end to find the start and end of the string that is between the similar "words".  The following will get the length of that string or -1 if one does not exist.

```
public int LengthBetween(string word, string input)
{
    int start = 0;
    int end = input.Length - 1;
    var letters = word.ToList();
    while(start < input.Length && letters.Count > 0)    
    {
        letters.Remove(input[start]);
        start++;
    }

    letters = word.ToList();
    while(end >= 0 && letters.Count > 0)    
    {
        letters.Remove(input[end]);
        end--;
    }

    if(start > end) return -1;
    return end - start + 1;
}
```

Then calling

```
LengthBetween("programmer", "progxrammerrxproxgrammer")
```

will return 2.

If instead you need the actual word just change the return type to `string` and change the end to

```
if(start > end) return null;
return input.Substring(start, end - start + 1);
```

Comment: @Jim.  No it doesn't.  I just ran his code with 'progxrammerrxproxgrammer' and it returns 2.

Comment: @Jim It returns 2 for me.  Did you make any changes to the code?  Also are you calling it like this `LengthBetween("programmer", "progxrammerrxproxgrammer")`.  Note it takes the "word" first and then the input to check for the "word".  If you mix those up it's going to return -1.

Comment: @juharr: shouldnt it be `LengthBetween("progxrammer", "progxrammerrxproxgrammer")`

Comment: @noobie-php No the user wanted to find "similar" words, or basically the letters of one word in order with potential additional letters added.  So it needs to work for "programmer" or "progxrammer".

Comment: Thanks, i saw the post again, just wanted to know how are you managing the x in progxrammer? i dont get the idea how are you handling it, sorry for my lack of expertise in C#, i have no clue around C#

Comment: @noobie-php Actually I misspoke, this does not care about the order of the letters in the word.  It just looks at each letter in the input and removes it from the list of letters in the word until we either remove them all or reach the end of the input.  So this would also work for "aegpgr" as well.

Answer (score 0):

this is my C++ approach.

## Idea

- If the length of the given string is less than the target string then
  ***NO ANSWER or -1***
- Otherwise, do the following thing:

  - Create a **map** (let's say target counter) to store the count of all characters in the target string.
  - See, since the target string size is fix we just have to look for `|given string size| - |target size| + 1` windows.
  - Use a while loop to iterate over all the windows and for each window create a counter (tmp Counter) to store all the counts.
  - Then, iterate over the target string & use the *target counter* and *tmp counter* to verify whether the current is valid or not.
  - If it is valid then store the index of the current window. This helps in calculating the distance.
- Then once we are done with that then for different cases, we will return appropriate results.

  - if no window is valid then, we will ***return -1***
  - if only one window is valid, then we will ***return 0*** because the distance of that window to itself is 0
  - if we have more than 1 window, then in the array (where you have stored all indices) use the 1st and last value to return the result. For the above case, the result will be ***difference between starting of the rightmost valid window to ending of leftmost valid window***.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<map>
#include<vector>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

int solve(string s, string t){
    
    if(s.size() < t.size()) return -1;
    map<char, int> tm;
    for(auto i : t) tm[i]++;
    
    
    int l = s.size(), g = t.size(), i = 0;
    
    vector<int> v;
    
    while(i < l-g+1)
    {   bool flag = true;
        map<char, int> tmpMap;
        for(int j = i; j<i+g; j++)
        {
            tmpMap[s[j]]++;
        }
        
        for(auto k: t){
            if(tm[k] != tmpMap[k])
            {
                flag = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        
        if(flag) v.push_back(i);
        i++;
    }
    
    
    if(v.size() == 0) return -1;
    if(v.size() == 1) return 0;
    // Ending of leftmost to starting of rightmost
    return v[v.size()-1] - v[0] - g;
}


int main(){
    int tcs;
    cin>>tcs;
    while(tcs--){
        string s, t;
        cin>>s>>t;
        cout<<solve(s, t)<<endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Recommending he use of `#include<bits/stdc++.h>` in an answer on Stack Overflow is really asking for downvotes. Please edit your code to use the relevant **standard** headers.

Comment: @AdrianMole Sorry I didn't know about this. Now you can see the appropriate libraries. Last but not least, thanks for making me aware of this "Recommending the use of #include<bits/stdc++.h> in an answer on Stack Overflow is really asking for downvotes".

Answer (score 0):

How about RegEx?

```
public int LengthBetween(string word, string input)
{
    var pattern = "p[^r]*r[^o]*o[^g]*g[^r]*r[^a]*a[^m]*m[^m]*m[^e]*e[^r]*r(.*)p[^r]*r[^o]*o[^g]*g[^r]*r[^a]*a[^m]*m[^m]*m[^e]*e[^r]*r";
    var match = Regex.Match(input, pattern);
    return match.Success ? match.Groups[1].Value.Length : -1;
}
```

This will work for `progxrammer rx proxgrammer` witch has additional letters. But if this should work with `xprogxrmaxemr pp prmmograeiruu` I would look for [Levenstein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) to check the grade of similarity.